# Computer name issue RDP

Tags: remote-desktop, computer-name

I have a user who setup a new server.  On the old server, he was able to RDP across our network to 'x' instead of 'x.department.school.com'.  I am unaware of any setting on the server or PC that enables this function (rather than typing out the full name).  Does anyone know?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser.  In the future, please include the OS.  I assume all of the machines involved are on various Windows versions.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a name resolution issue.  If this is windows, check the file `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` (it's a plain text file) and see if there is a line in it with an IP address followed by `x`.  If so, then that either needs to be updated with the address of the new server, or a new line needs to be added for the new server.  Note: you'll need to edit this file with administrative permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!  I found the file you speak of but there isn't anything listed in it.

Comment: @Becca Ok, just to confirm - It's the same PC that he's using to RDP to the new server that he used to RDP to the old server?  And, what OS and version is it?

Comment: Correct.  PC is windows 10, server is Windows Server 2019.

Comment: @Becca The answer that Daniel B gave is the next thing I was going to offer up

Answer (score 0):

Most operating systems support a so-called DNS suffix, usually set by DHCP. When you enter a domain name that is not fully qualified (like `x`), the resolver also tries `x.the-suffix.` and not only `x.` (which most likely does not exist).

Since you have a server, it probably has a static IP address and does not use DHCP. In that case, you need to set the desired DNS suffix manually. The old server(s) probably had the DNS suffix set.

On Linux: In `/etc/resolv.conf`, have a line like this:

```
search my.suffix
```

On Windows: Either change the primary DNS suffix or, on the network interface(s), set the connection-specific DNS suffix:

[image: Windows advanced IP settings]

To get there, from the connection properties, select IPv4, then Properties → Advanced → DNS.

To change the primary DNS suffix, run `sysdm.cpl`, select Change → More and enter the desired suffix.